# What is the lowest pressure at which plants can survive?

Tags: botany, astrobiology

What is the lowest pressure at which plants can survive? How the plants behave in a Martian-type atmosphere? Is there any plant that can survive such atmosphere?

Can a lichen grow at Martian pressure?

Comment: Are you referring to total air pressure or partial pressures of oxygen and carbon dioxide?

Comment: Lichen is not a plant though.

Answer (score 23):

I like your question!

Low surface pressure on Mars (averaging 600 Pa or about 1/170 of Earth's at sea level) is only one difficulty that an organism would have to contend with. In addition, mean surface temperatures are ~210 K (- 63 °C), the surface ultraviolet flux is extremely high (no ozone layer) and an aridity comparable to the Atacama desert. On the plus side, a 95% CO<sub>2</sub> atmosphere might promote photosynthesis.

So, higher plants are extremely unlikely to prosper on Mars. Purely in terms of pressure, [experiments suggest](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2004/25feb_greenhouses/) that at 1/10 Earth atmospheric pressure vascular plant transpiration increases significantly. So much so that they enter into a drought response which often leads to plant death.

However, lichens may be another matter. These are often adapted to low precipitation/pressure environments such as high mountains. Indeed, this [article](http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/ast.2009.0362) addresses exactly your question (sadly it is not open access). The authors suggest that the lichen [*Xanthoria elegans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthoria_elegans) experiences **no loss** in vitality after 22 days exposure to laboratory Mars-like conditions (low pressure, low temperature etc.)!

Having skimmed this article I am frankly amazed (and slightly dubious) at the result. However, it should be noted that they only ran the experiment for 22 days, applied no ionising radiation (to simulate the high UV flux) and make little mention of the precise metabolic state of the lichen. If it has entered into cryptobiosis (cessation of metabolic processes) then it can't exactly be regarded as prospering.

- de Vera et al., 2010, *Astrobiology*, 10, 2, *Survival Potential and Photosynthetic Activity of Lichens Under Mars-Like Conditions : A Laboratory Study*

Answer (score 4):

Short answer : around 0.47 atm

World's highest [plants discovered growing 6 km above sea level](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2114856-worlds-highest-plants-discovered-growing-6km-above-sea-level/)

If [this](https://www.mide.com/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator) Air Pressure Calculator is to be believed that should be 0.47 [atm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_(unit)), so for [plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant) **'the lowest pressure at which plants can survive is around 0.47 atm'** seems to be your answer.

The air pressure on [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars) is 0.00628 atm, so no, plants can't survive on Mars, if they could then we'd certainly find them far above 6 km on mountains on [Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth).

***Howsoever***

It does seem that some of [Earth’s toughest life could survive on Mars](https://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/20120515-earth-life-survive-mars.html).

The life in that article that (not only) survived (but flourished in) the environment in the chamber (which included the atmospheric pressure of Mars) where [Lichens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) & [Cyanobacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria).

Neither of those are plants though.

> [Cyanobacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria) are bacteria.
>
> [lichens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichen) are a composite organism incorporating a fungus & algae or cyanobacteria.
>
> [Algae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algae) are plants, but it's in a lichen, not a standalone plant, it's not clear from the article any of those lichens were algal rather than ones with cyanobacteria either.

But (that bit of pedantry aside) it would seem the answer to your second question is yes.

A lichen can grow at Martian pressure.

So there are examples of life that clearly can survive lower pressures than 0.47 atm.

But actual plants don't seem to be among them.

Answer (score 4):

No, the lowest pressure at which plants can survive is not around 0.47 atm.

It is 0.07 atm or less in the case of ryegrass. And it's the total pressure. Not partial pressure of one of the constituent gases.

See this article:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19860010460.pdf

Answer (score 1):

... almost 8 years later..

A newer experiment with a timespan of 1.5 years on another one lichen species suggests that there is

> .. a minor resistance potential of the lichen **[Buellia frigida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buellia)** towards
>   Low Earth Orbit and Mars analogue conditions effecting the survival
>   potential and the resistance of the symbiotic organism

due to a DNA damage.

[Source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063318302927): "*DNA damage of the lichen Buellia frigida after 1.5 years in space using Randomly Amplified Polymorphic DNA (RAPD) technique*" Backhaus et al, 2019 Planetary and Space Science

So the answer is possibly "no" until we find some Martian lichen.

Comment: It looks like this study is mostly showing the effects of *radiation exposure* in space rather than *atmospheric pressure*.