# Could a tree grow in a low pressure environment?

Tags: botany, trees

Could a tree grow in a low pressure environment? If you had a pressure say, 10% of that of Sea level could a tree grow if it was in the proper soil and watered regularly?

Comment: related https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/what-is-the-lowest-pressure-at-which-plants-can-survive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the lowest pressure at which plants can survive?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/what-is-the-lowest-pressure-at-which-plants-can-survive)